# Copyfile in matlab from one directory to another

Tags: matlab, filepath, file-management, file-copying

I have a short question regarding the `copyfile` function within MATLAB. Basically I want to copy a file from a different user selected directory/file to the current directory (where the function is run from). I am struggling with how to do this.

So far I have:

```
[jxlfilename,jxlfilepath] = uigetfile({'*.jxl'}, 'Pick a File');
copyfile(????)
```

I have read the help that MATLAB offers, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were almost there, once your selected your file do:

```
copyfile(strcat(jxlfilepath,jxlfilename))
```

and if you don't specify a second argument copyfile will copy the file to the current folder and the `strcat(jxlfilepath,jxlfilename)` will construct the string with path and filename.
Or

```
copyfile(strcat(jxlfilepath,jxlfilename),'newname.jxl')
```

if you want to assign a new name to the file.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for [`copyfile`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyfile.html) is

```
copyfile(source,destination);
```

The function to concatenate paths and filenames is [`fullfile`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) .
The current directory is selected with `.`

Together this gives you

```
[jxlfilename,jxlfilepath] = uigetfile({'*.jxl'}, 'Pick a File');
copyfile(fullfile(jxlfilepath,jxlfilename),'.');
```